# Struts2 cross context JSP access using c:import throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I have a couple of web apps deployed on the same server. There's a JSP in app1 that I want to access from app2. I enabled cross context access in the tomcat and tried this JSTL tag:

```
<c:import url="/pages/myJSP.jsp" context="/app1" />
```

The `myJSP.jsp` uses some struts2 tags itself.

I also made sure the required libraries are on both the app1 and app2's lib directory. During the runtime though, the app2's page won't render and I see this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack cannot be cast to
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack   at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:53)  at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)

Any idea why? If I copied the jsp to the app2 and referenced it using the same c:import tag, it works just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do such things. The web applications are protected and isolated from each other to run in the same container. For further descriptions and clarification see [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) guide.

If you want to share resources from different modules you need to copy them at the build time.

Comment: How do I copy them over at the build time? Does maven have options for this?

Comment: With the Ant you can do this, there's also an option for Maven integration with Ant.

Comment: Can't seem to find any reference for this, got one?

Comment: You could even do it with maven resources plugin like in this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html). Couple of years ago I used it with IntelliJ Idea Modules to share one module between others it  perfectly copies resources.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm gonna give this a try!